# Symfony2 : customize error pages for different bundles

Tags: symfony, bundles

I have several bundles and I'd like to know if it is possible to **customize for each bundle their own error pages**.

I read the cookbook and the examples show only a generic customize page for all bundles.

Is there a way to override the exception process for each bundle ?

Answer (score 5):

The listener itself would have to detect that - I'm not aware of any way to specify a listener for a single bundle.

```
<?

namespace Your\MainBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class YourExceptionListener
{
  public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
  {
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $namespace = new \ReflectionObject( $event->getController() )->getNamespaceName();

    switch ( $namespace )
    {
      case 'Acme\\DemoBundle':
        // do whatever with $exception here
        break;
      case 'Some\\OtherBundle':
        // do whatever with $exception here
        break;
      case 'Your\\MainBundle':
        // do whatever with $exception here
        break;
      default;
        // default
    }
  }
}
```

And register it

```
//services.yml
kernel.listener.yourlistener:
  class: Your\MainBundle\YourExceptionListener
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a bundle i've made for catch different errors pages from routes regex configuration, it works from the "kernel.exception_listener" listener and the "kernel.exception" event as described in documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#use-kernel-exception-event).

With this bundle, you can:

- Change the twig exception template from regex of the route you want
- Change the twig exception template for certains http status code only
- Enable / Disable the custom template for the debug mode

Link to the bundle (MIT licence): https://github.com/Kwrz/TwigException

Thanks for your idea Peter, I think add a feature in the next version of my bundle to define the template from the corresponding bundle namespace.